# Conditionals & Control Flow - Code Academy

Tags: python

I'm taking the Python course in Code Academy. I have never been good at math, never put much effort into it to be honest. My question is, below, when they say "Set bool_three equal to the result of 100 ** 0.5 >= 50 or False" as an example is "100 ** 0.5 >= 50 or False" - Just an example made up or would I be needing numbers like that when I start coding Python on my own? I have been doing great in the course so far, but when i get to questions like that I go brain dead for a second, I end up figuring it out, given some of them I do need to look up, but is this going to be a common theme I'm going to use when coding or did just explain it this way?

Thanks

```
Time to practice with or!

Set bool_one equal to the result of 2**3 == 108 % 100 or 'Cleese' == 'King Arthur'
Set bool_two equal to the result of True or False
Set bool_three equal to the result of 100**0.5 >= 50 or False
Set bool_four equal to the result of True or True
Set bool_five equal to the result of 1**100 == 100**1 or 3 * 2 * 1 != 3 + 2 + 1
```

Comment: You can do math at the Python prompt.  Just type e.g. `2**3` and it will print `8`.

Comment: "would I be needing numbers like that when I start coding Python" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: `100**0.5` is bigger than or equal to `50`. This means the square root of `100`, which is `10`, is bigger than (or equal to) `50`. This is `True`.

Comment: @scrappedcola - As an example "Set bool_five equal to the result of 1**100 == 100**1 or 3 * 2 * 1 != 3 + 2 + 1"   - Starting from the first number to the last, that is what confused me, I was was asking when i am coding from scratch if its common i will be using numbers and math like that? - FYI after going through this course a couple of times im going to learn either Flask or Django so I can create web apps.

Comment: It depends on what you end up coding. To be honest that little line of code is pretty trivial compared to some of the stuff you could end up coding. But I still don't really understand what your sticking point is? That line isn't anything you really need to compute but a logic statement that you need to translate to python. It's not about math, but can you use the tools in python to evaluate and set the variable correctly.

Comment: ie: `bool_five = 1100 == 1001 or 'Cleese' == 'King Arthur'`

Answer (score 0):

What kind of math you will need depends entirely on your application. YOUR code, may not use math at all and all math needed is done by libraries and frameworks you use. - There is always math involved, whether you have contact with it is another question.

If you develop a solver for equations, then chances are, most of your code will end up "beeing maths".

If you meant to ask, if it's common to use boolean logic crossed with math, then in my experience, no it isn't. Typically you have flow control dictate which piece of math is used and then proceed. You don't mangle it all into a single expression.

Comment: Ok great, since its done by the libaries and frameworks if anything it will be at my fingertips in the documentation im guessing? Unless i throw in something random(Which i dont see why why right now) - My thought exactly they where just using that an example for the course.

Comment: Depends really. Documentation for a 2d collision library typically tells you how to use it, how accurate it is etc. . But not how they made it work in the math department - you oftentimes can just look into their source code, anyway.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. The math part is all on me IF needed.After I go through this tutorial and memorize it well enough what do you suggest next, Flask, Django or start with one then the other?

Comment: So your goal is web applications?
Flask is simple, while django is the large and powerful Framework.
There's a lot more than just web apps you can do with python though.

Comment: Right now, yes. Been putting off a site idea I had for over 7 months, I have to get it done. I can technically use any language for it but that exactly why I chose Python, for that exact reason you stated. Extremely versatile and have the choice at any point to basically create what I want - Im a very big idea person

Comment: Good luck to you then.

Comment: Thanks, Ill be asking more questions as time goes on im sure, until i get the gist of it at least. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Math (algebra) and programming are really coupled in my head. Being good at math would sharpen your skills in problems solving.

Don't worry! That's a thing that you can acquire by learning more about problems solving. You don't have to take classes in Math! (Even though it would still be better to improve the Math part by taking classes).

From the example you given, I can see that it caught your attention in the sense that you possibly were like:

> OMG! Math?!!!!

The example is nothing at all. Therefore, this kind of math would be required to comprehend whilst you are taking the programming course. That's of course if you are interested to be a good programmer.

stackoverflow is here and always will be. Whenever you have questions about some problems you don't know how to work it out, just post your questions. That's how we all learn ;)

Happy learning.